# How is "Restrict Background Data" enforced in the Android stack?

Tags: android, android-networking

Does anyone know just where in the Android stack the "Restrict Background Data" setting is enforced and how it is enforced?  (I.e. apps in the background are not allowed to use the phone data network while running in the background - WIFI not affected.)

Thanks much,

Dawg

Answer (score 0):

Android uses iptables rules as on any linux box to restrict data-access to certain users (every user downloaded app on android runs under its own unique user id).

If you wish to remove restriction for your app, you can remove the rule from a root shell.

```
iptables -F penalty_box -j REJECT
```

or on newer devices, as below:

```
iptables -F bw_penalty_box -j REJECT
```

However on a restart, Android will **re-enforce** the rule to iptables automatically. To prevent this, you need to remove `<uid-policy ...>` from "**/data/system/netpolicy.xml**". Global Restrict Background Data settings can be removed by setting "**restrictBackgroundData**" atribute to "false" on `<policy-list ...>` node.

Along with the *netpolicy.xml* changes, you must perform a reboot for your changes to take effect.

Note: Any of these operations may require to be run as **root**.